# Repeatable read and lock compatibility table

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, isolation-level

I think I have understood the answers from that question :

[Repeatable Read - am I understanding this right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065627/repeatable-read-am-i-understanding-this-right)

but I have a complementary question for the repeatable read scenario.
It is said :

**REPEATABLE READ**

```
1 SELECT -- places a shared lock and keeps it
2 UPDATE -- tries to places an exclusive lock but it's not compatible with the shared lock. Locks
1 SELECT -- the lock is already placed. Succeeds.
```

But what if the update is made by transaction 1 ? Will it be blocked too because of non compatible lock ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: sql server. I just read that compatibility table is for concurrent transactions only so I guess my question was stupid ^^  : the update is not blocked if it is done by transaction1. Thx anyway